# How to delete generated unit test data only?

Tags: unit-testing, intersystems-cache, objectscript

I use this code to create data:

```
Method OnBeforeAllTests() As %Status
{
    // Create one MyClass row   
    Do ##class(MyClass).Populate(1)
    Quit $$$OK
}
```

and this to delete data:

```
Method OnAfterAllTests() As %Status
{
    Do ##class(MyClass).%KillExtent()
    Quit $$$OK
}
```

How do I change `OnAfterAllTests` to only delete the data I populated using `OnBeforeAllTests` and not delete any other data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that might auto-magically keep track of what you have done and roll it back would be a transaction.

Other than that you need to keep track of it yourself, or just not have your unit tests actually create data.  It's not a very good practice to have test specific code in your production system, so a flag field "testData" isn't great, but I guess you could.

My personal solution has been to create tests that don't actually insert data in the first place, but this has required using dependency injection and creating a mocking framework to make writing the unit tests feasible.

A somewhat easier solution might be to have an object that keeps track of all your data changes and rolls them back at the end, but probably just using a transaction will do a better job of this.

Comment: Hmm - that is what I was afraid of.  Do you by chance have that DI stuff published some place :)?

Comment: @O.O - I can't publish the DI or the mocking frameworks I'm afraid.  You don't *really* need a DI framework if you are willing to do that by hand.  The mocking probably saves more time (Cache has a fair amount of ceremony in creating an object and all those mock and stub classes add up).  I could answer SO questions about doing DI or mocking frameworks in cache </hint>.

Comment: By the way - the Intersystem's built in unit testing framework writes out class definitions to disk, doesn't it?  Isn't that going to get slow for lots of tests?

Comment: Heh, perhaps I will ask a question about that once I take a stab at it.  Well, so far it is not that slow (with 4 test classes).  I only have to export it to disk once manually, and after that I can just use RunTest.  Of course compared to nunit or MSTest running tests is magnitudes slower.

Comment: @psr - InterSystem's unit testing framework will log its results to the database so that you can see what passed when at a later point (even Microsoft's unit test framework does the same thing in Visual Studio).  O.O - That's very minimal overhead compared to actually reading and/or writing data from the database [i]in the tests themselves[/i] like you were trying.  As psr hinted at, you should really avoid doing that, as it can slow down your tests depending on what you're testing, and it also couples your tests to your database.  It's sometimes tricky to avoid doing, but well worth it.